# Version loaded from file does not comply with PEP 440

Tags: python-3.x, setuptools

As the title states, I am getting this ERROR when I run `python -m build` locally using a version file. I  have read the [PEP 440](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/) and to me, it appears compliant. I cannot see from the [documentation on setuptools](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html) why I would be running into this issue

I would really appreciate some help on this since I don't see how I am able to run a debugger on `python -m build` or get some more understanding of specifically why the `_parse_version` of `setuptools/config.py` is unhappy with my version file.

More details:

I have a project structured as follows:

```
src/
   mypackage/
      __init__.py
      VERSION
pyproject.toml
setup.cfg
setup.py
```

VERSION

```
0.0.1
```

setup.cfg

```yaml
name = mypackage
version = file: src/mypackage/VERSION
# etc. etc. etc.
```

setup.py

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Used to create editable installs
import setuptools

setuptools.setup()
```

pyproject.toml

```yaml
[build-system]
# Minimum requirements for the build system to execute.
requires = [
    "setuptools>=42",
    "wheel"]  # PEP 508 specifications.
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

More detail on the error:

```sh
  File "/tmp/build-env-2kboopyp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 154, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
    return self._get_build_requires(
  File "/tmp/build-env-2kboopyp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 135, in _get_build_requires
    self.run_setup()
  File "/tmp/build-env-2kboopyp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 150, in run_setup
    exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
  File "setup.py", line 5, in <module>
    setuptools.setup()
  File "/tmp/build-env-2kboopyp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 153, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/core.py", line 121, in setup
    dist.parse_config_files()
  File "/tmp/build-env-2kboopyp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_virtualenv.py", line 21, in parse_config_files
    result = old_parse_config_files(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/tmp/build-env-2kboopyp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 778, in parse_config_files
    parse_configuration(self, self.command_options,
  File "/tmp/build-env-2kboopyp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/config.py", line 157, in parse_configuration
    meta.parse()
  File "/tmp/build-env-2kboopyp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/config.py", line 463, in parse
    section_parser_method(section_options)
  File "/tmp/build-env-2kboopyp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/config.py", line 436, in parse_section
    self[name] = value
  File "/tmp/build-env-2kboopyp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/config.py", line 220, in __setitem__
    value = parser(value)
  File "/tmp/build-env-2kboopyp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/config.py", line 553, in _parse_version
    raise DistutilsOptionError(tmpl.format(**locals()))
distutils.errors.DistutilsOptionError: Version loaded from file: src/mypackage/VERSION does not comply with PEP 440: 

ERROR Backend subproccess exited when trying to invoke get_requires_for_build_wheel
```

Comment: Have you tried things like `./setup.py --version` or `./setup.py check`? Are you able to build distributions with `./setup.py sdist bdist_wheel` and do they have correct version strings (in the filename and in metadata)?

Comment: I ran `python setup.py --version` and showed the correct version in the file. I changed the version and ran again and it was still correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have solved this though I'm not happy with the current documentation or error messaging, as it stands I feel it's quite easy to fall into this trap.

So the solution was to create a `MANIFEST.in` file with the line:
`include src/mypackage/VERSION` at top level of my repo:

```
src/
   mypackage/
      __init__.py
      VERSION
pyproject.toml
setup.cfg
setup.py
MANIFEST.in
```

Additionally, the following must be added to the `setup.cfg`

```yaml
[options]
include_package_data = True
```

From [docs](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/references/keywords.html):

> `include_package_data` If set to True, this tells setuptools to automatically include any data files it finds inside your package directories that are specified by your MANIFEST.in file. For more information, see the section on Including Data Files.

The [setuptools documentation](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html) V57.1.0 had me believe it would be included:

> Automatically include all relevant files in your source distributions, without needing to create a MANIFEST.in file, and without having to force regeneration of the MANIFEST file when your source tree changes.

And intuitively I would have thought a `file:` key word with the path would be sufficient, or that the error message which as it turns out was produced because there was no such file, might have clued me in some more. This is also not apparent from the [packaging-projects](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/)

But I suppose it can be inferred from the [MANIFEST.in documentation](https://packaging.python.org/guides/using-manifest-in/).

I say all this since incase anyone has anything useful to add or counter reason my current feeling: that there might be an omission from the current guides regarding using a version file.

Comment: Ah right, you need the file in the `sdist` distribution. So it makes sense to add it to `MANIFEST.in` (although, yes _setuptools_ could add it automatically since it knows it is required). But it should not be necessary in the `wheel` or any of the `bdist`. So I wonder if you really need the `include_package_data = True`...